# How to choose which JSON file to use in your D3 force directed graph

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, xmlhttprequest

I have a force directed graph and when it runs I wish to be able to change what JSON file gets read, thus, changing the data/force directed graph.

I can change it in the HTML by changing the file name but I wish to do this asynchronously.

I have looked at `AJAX` and `XHR (XMLHttpRequest)` but I don't know where to start

Comment: This question is quite broad. Start with creating the UI element you want to serve as the selector (could be a [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element or something custom), then set up an listener to receive events when the user changes the selection. Then you can start working on how to load a new file (and yes, ajax or d3.json is the way to load that file).

Comment: thanks @meetamit shall look at this when I can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is a broad question, so here's a broad answer: If you're using `d3.json`, then you're probably looking at something like:

```
d3.json("graphdata1.json", createMyGraph);
```

You can instead use a string variable to refer to the filename and modify that as needed:

```
var graphFilename = "defaultGraph.json";
// Some kind of logic gets a different filename from a selector resulting in something like
graphFilename = "newGraphData.json";

d3.json(graphFilename, createMyGraph);
```

If you want to transition a drawn graph to another, that's a more involved process (and a different question) involving `.enter()` and `.exit()` and update behavior.

Comment: cheers for the input, hopefully pointing me in the right direction :)) thankyou